# Python Decorators import time

Tags: python, import, decorator

I am registering some of my functions in a global set:

```py
# registry.py
import functools

schedule_registry = set()


def register_scheduler(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper():
        print(f"adding {func.__name__}")
        schedule_registry.add(func)
        return func

    return func_wrapper


@register_scheduler
def foo():
    print("running foo")
```

Now, I expect `schedule_registry` to be filled at import-time (and "adding..." to be printed), but to my surprise:

```py
In [1]: import registry                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [2]:
```

Nothing is being printed.

Thing is, if I change the decorator to the following:

```py
def register_scheduler():
    def func_wrapper(func):
        print(f"adding {func.__name__}")
        schedule_registry.add(func)
        return func

    return func_wrapper

@register_scheduler()
def foo():
    print("running foo")
```

I get what I expect:

```py
In [1]: import registry                                                                                                                                                                                           
adding foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with `wraps`.

You haven't understood how decorators work. The outer function is called at import time, and returns the inner function that replaces the function being decorated. The inner function is then called in place of the original function, so needs to take its original arguments - *not* `func`. If you want anything to happen at import time, it needs to go in the outer function.

```
def register_scheduler(func):
    print(f"adding {func.__name__}")
    schedule_registry.add(func)

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       print(f"at call time")
       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return func_wrapper
```

Note that neither of your examples would actually work at all; the first one doesn't call the decorated function, and the second one calls the inner function at import time leaving nothing in place of the function being decorated.

Comment: Great explanation, although not entirely correct. The second example does work - ```In [1]: from registry import *                                                                                                                                                                                    
adding foo

In [2]: foo()                                                                                                                                                                                                      
running foo()```

Answer (score 1):

To fulfill your task: adding to a set, but not changing behavior, you don't need functools. Instead you just need a simple function which returns your function.

Try this on:

```
schedule_registry = set()

def register_scheduler(func):
  print(f"adding {func.__name__}")
  schedule_registry.add(func)
  return func

@register_scheduler
def foo():
    print("running foo")

@register_scheduler
def bar():
    print("running bar")

print(f"now running foo..., and registry has {len(schedule_registry)} items")

foo()
```

And you should see:

```
adding foo
adding bar
now running foo..., and registry has 2 items
running foo
```